# How to specify multiple conditions for $sum - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Following is the sample data for TShirts which contains all the available sizes for a specific color.

```
{
    _id: '591c0e588834491a10a584ef',
    prdctName: 'TShirt',
    ColorRed: [38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48], 
    ColorPink: [38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48],    
    ColorOrange: [38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48]   
}
```

I want to calculate how many TShirts do I have for a specified size.
e.g I want to find total number of TShirts available for size '38' across different colors.

Thanks!

Comment: Your not really giving people a lot to go on. For example, How many T-shirts are there meant to be in the present sample? Are there "three" given the choice of colors for the given size? Are the colors consistent on all documents in the collection? Do you know the names of all possible color keys? Are you committed to this data format or looking for options of how to best structure to your needs? These are all the things lacking from your question in order to be clear and get the result you want. Needs work.

Comment: There are three colors represented by fields named 'ColorRed', 'ColorPink', 'ColorOrange'. Each color field (e.g. ColorPink) may or may not  contain  sizes from 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 46. So in the current example total number of TShirts are 3 feilds * 6 sizes = 18 TShirts. There is NO SCOPE for modifying structure.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to filter by product, then unwind all sises and find count for selected size. First query that come to my mind is:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
    { $match: {prdctName:"TShirt"}},
    { $project: { prdctName:"$prdctName", allColors: { $concatArrays: [ "$ColorRed", "$ColorPink", "$ColorOrange" ] }} },
    { $unwind: "$allColors"},
    { $match: { allColors: 38 }},
    { $group: { _id: "$prdctName", count:{$sum:1}}},
])
```

P.S. It might not be the optimal one, but is something to start from.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient I can see is using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to reduce to the matched elements and then simply [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the remaining array:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Only match potential documents
  { "$match": {
     "prdctName": "TShirt",
     "$or": [
       { "ColorRed": 38 },
       { "ColorPink": 38 },
       { "ColorOrange": 38 }
     ]
  }},
  // Group and count the matching elements from the combined arrays
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$prdctName",
    "count": { 
       "$sum": { 
         "$size": {
           "$filter": {
             "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$ColorRed", "$ColorOrange", "$ColorPink" ] },
             "as": "el",
             "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el", 38 ] }
           }
       }
    }
  }}

])
```

That makes it an efficient two step process of filtering out the possible matching documents and then doing the accumulation in a single pass.